# How can I generate multiple result dataframes using filter in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows. I would like to generate a separate dataframe per Country using filter. Is there a way I could do this in one command, instead of manually repeating the code per Country?

```
Country_List <- c("India", "Japan", "Korea")

library(dplyr)

Dat %>% filter(grepl('Japan', Country))
```

| Country | Variable 1 | Variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 1 | B |
| Japan | 2 | B |
| Korea | 2 | C |
| India | 1 | D |
| Japan | 2 | C |
| Korea | 3 | C |
| India | 3 | A |
| Japan | 2 | A |
| India | 1 | A |
| Japan | 1 | B |
| Korea | 3 | D |
| Japan | 2 | B |
| Korea | 4 | C |

Comment: You should use `split`: `split(Dat, Dat$Country)`, or `group_split(Dat, Country)` in `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `group_split` that will give you a list of tibbles

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_split(Country)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Country Variable1 Variable2
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
1 India           1 B        
2 India           1 D        
3 India           3 A        
4 India           1 A        

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Country Variable1 Variable2
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
1 Japan           2 B        
2 Japan           2 C        
3 Japan           2 A        
4 Japan           1 B        
5 Japan           2 B        

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Country Variable1 Variable2
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
1 Korea           2 C        
2 Korea           3 C        
3 Korea           3 D        
4 Korea           4 C
```

Data:

```
library(readr)

df <- read_table("Country   Variable1   Variable2
India   1   B
Japan   2   B
Korea   2   C
India   1   D
Japan   2   C
Korea   3   C
India   3   A
Japan   2   A
India   1   A
Japan   1   B
Korea   3   D
Japan   2   B
Korea   4   C")
```